# How to get params in React Navigation in class-based components?

Tags: react-native, parameters, expo, react-navigation

**Platform: React Native (Expo)**

I want to get my params to a new screen using **class-based** components and React Navigation **6.0**.

This is how I am sending the params:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("BlogDetails", { blogID: item.ID });
```

and this is how I'm retrieving it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { blogID } = this.props.route.params;
    this.setState({ blobID: blogID });
    console.log(this.state.blobID);
  }
```

There are no errors, however, the `console.log()` returns `""`.

I am unable to find where I'm going wrong but I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere during the retrieval, I'm pretty confident that the data is being sent to the screen.

Comment: Typo blobID -> blogID

Comment: @MichaelBahl I don't think there's a typo. My state is **blob** while the var is **blog** and I have **blob** first and **blog** after, which is how its supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

state doesn't update immediately, if you want use state after update should act like this

```
componentDidMount() {
 const { blogID } = this.props.route.params;
 this.setState({ blobID: blogID }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.blobID);
 });
}
```

Comment: The `console.log()` is just for testing purposes. I am trying to render the data using a `FlatList` later and all I get is an empty screen indicating that there is no data in the state.

Comment: share your complete code please

Answer (score 0):

```
const {paramName1, paramName2, ...} = this.props.navigation.state.params
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems different for react navigation version.

```
const { blogID } = this.props.route.params;
```

or

```
const blogID = this.props.route.getParam('blogID);
```

try to use getParam function.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params/